# Does SQL Azure/ SQL Server Transparent Data Encryption encrypt .bacpac files?

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

I am looking into implementing Transparent Data Encryption (TDE) on a SQL Azure database.  Azure creates backups as .bacpac files. The documentation at [TDE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934049.aspx) mentions that

"Backup files of databases that have TDE enabled are also encrypted by using the database encryption key. "

The documentation does not mention anything about .bak or .bacpac files specifically. Does anyone have experience, and more importantly, official documentation, that TDE will encrypt .bacpac files?

Any pointers and suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE: 
I was able to find official documentation here [TDE Azure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn948096.aspx) .  At the bottom of the page it says that .bapacpac files are not ecrypted.

I feel like this is a huge drawback to TDE on SQL Azure, as I really like the feature that prevents .bak files from being restored on another server without the certificate/key used in the TDE.

Comment: The point of TDE is that the data is encrypted in storage, but completely transparent to normal operations. Backups just take your stored data and compress them to a single file, so it will remain encrypted. The effort to read the data out, re-construct everything without TDE and archive would be very noticeable (both CPU and disk usage would be very high).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

.bak and .bacpac files are very different. .bak files are copies of the database file pages. .bacpac files are created by scripting out the TSQL statements to recreate the schema of a database and using Bulk Export to query and export the rows of all the tables. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213241.aspx list item #2 under "Before You Begin" to see that .bacpac file data is extracted using bulk operations.

TDE works by encrypting the database file pages, but leaving the in memory version of the files in plaintext so they can be queried. Since .bak files are copies of the database file pages, they are encrypted. Since the data in .bacpac files are the output queries, they are plaintext and unencrypted just as bcp out files are from TDE databases.

Comment: So does that mean that TDE on SQL Azure v12 cannot be "fully" implemented?  SQL Azure, as far as I have read, does not currently support creation of .bak files.  All backups are created as .bacpac files. So if someone gets a hold of the bacpac file they can restore it to another server without needing the certificate/keys used to implement TDE?

Comment: .Bacpac files are only used for exporting out of Azure SQL Database. All copies, point in time backups, restores, geo-replications, etc. that stay within SQL Database are protected.

When exporting, you can use the Import and Export Wizard to create the .bacpac file directly on an encrypted volume, thus protecting even the exports of the database file.